# "Convexity" and Difference of Eigenvalues of a Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the ordered set of eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ of a matrix $A$ with $\lambda_n=\lambda_\mathrm{min}$ the smallest eigenvalue and $\lambda_1=\lambda_\mathrm{max}$ the largest eigenvalue, such that we have
$$\lambda_\mathrm{max}\geq\lambda_2\geq\lambda_3\geq\dots\geq\lambda_\mathrm{min}.$$
Are there conditions such that the eigenvalues are "convex" (in a handwavy sense)
$$\Delta^2\lambda_k=\lambda_{k-1}-2\lambda_k+\lambda_{k+1}>0,\quad 2\leq k\leq n-1$$
i.e. that all eigenvalues have a positive "second derivative"/curvature?
We can assume $A$ to be positive definite, real, symmetric and invertible (thus all eigenvalues are real and strictly greater than zero) and on top of that it's writeable as $A=\boldsymbol{1}+B^\mathsf{T}B$ thus all eigenvalues are larger than $1$.

For what I'm researching, if this is too hard, is it possible to give conditions for a statement with the same consequences:
$$\lambda_k\leq\frac{n\lambda_\mathrm{min}}{k}$$
or say something about the difference between two eigenvalues:
$$\Delta\lambda_k=\lambda_k-\lambda_{k+1},$$
i.e. bounds or its behavior?

Comment: You refer to $\lambda_k$, where $k \in [0, 1]$. The only $k$ for which this is sensible is $k = 1$, where $\lambda_k = \lambda_1 = \lambda_\min$.

Comment: There's still an issue with $k = 0$, given $\lambda_k$ begins at $1$, but this could be easily remedied. Once you do, you'll have a sensible definition at least, one that matrices may or may not satisfy. The next question is, what do you want to do with this definition? I don't see it as particularly natural, as depositing eigenvalues at integer points seems somewhat arbitrary to me, so I don't hold out great hope that this will be a useful definition. What property are you hoping to capture here?

Comment: The statement is obvious for nonnegative numbers as $\lambda_k\le \lambda_{max}.$ Perhaps you have to divide by $n,$ i.e. you are after $$\lambda_k\le {k\over n}\lambda_{max} +{n-k\over n}\lambda_{min}$$ But then for $\lambda_k=\sqrt{k} $ you will have the opposite inequality. You should not expect that an arbitrary collection of numbers is either convex or concave.

Comment: Take $\lambda_1=0, $ $\lambda_2=\ldots = \lambda_n=1.$ Then $$\lambda_1-2\lambda_2+\lambda_3=-1$$ On the other hand $\lambda_1=0,$ $\lambda_2=1,$ $\lambda_3=3$ $$\lambda_1-2\lambda_2+\lambda_3=1$$

Comment: I'm mainly interested in criteria such that $A$ has this property

Comment: This is a question about numbers. An increasing sequence of numbers is convex exactly when it is convex. No more can be said.

Comment: Thinking it through, it mainly boils down to asking how the coefficients of a polynomial should be chosen such that the ordered set of polynomial roots is convex. Because using the Cayley–Hamilton theorem allows us to connect it back to matrices

Comment: Writing "for simplicity" is technically correct, but I'd say that the question is totally different (and may not even make much sense) without the requirement that $A$ is symmetric.